# How can I enhance this loop (and are there other solutions than for loops)?

Tags: r, performance, for-loop

This is a combination problem.  I have 10 shops. I want to find the best 8 shops which minimize the sum of distances from my 100 observations.

From the combination matrix 'test_comb_matrix', I wish to extract combinations of 8 at each iteration of choose(10, 8).
I then apply those indices to the distance matrix 'test_dist_matrix' and record distances. I use pmin() to find the closest shop for each observation, then record the minimum in myminCol.

Below is my code (scroll down for reproducible code). I want to remove the 'a to h' bit.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(testDat))
{
  print(i)

  # get indices from combination matrix
  a <- test_comb_matrix[1, i]
  b <- test_comb_matrix[2, i]
  c <- test_comb_matrix[3, i]
  d <- test_comb_matrix[4, i]
  e <- test_comb_matrix[5, i]
  f <- test_comb_matrix[6, i]
  g <- test_comb_matrix[7, i]
  h <- test_comb_matrix[8, i]

  # find the minimum
  myminCol <- as.vector(pmin(test_dist_matrix[, a], test_dist_matrix[, b],
                             test_dist_matrix[, c], test_dist_matrix[, d],
                             test_dist_matrix[, e], test_dist_matrix[, f],
                             test_dist_matrix[, g], test_dist_matrix[, h]))
  # sum distances
  mySum <- sum(myminCol)

  testDat[i, 1] <- mySum
}
```

Reproducible code:

```
# number of combinations from 10 choose 8 
n <- choose(10, 8)

# get combination matrix
test_comb_matrix <- combn(1:10, 8)
# view first 5 combinations
test_comb_matrix[, 1:5]

# create distance matrix for 100 observations and 10 columns
test_dist_matrix <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100), nrow = 100, ncol = 10))


testDat <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = n, ncol = 1))
names(testDat) <- "min"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this :

```
result_vec <-  sapply(seq_len(nrow(testDat)), function(i) 
  sum(matrixStats::rowMins(as.matrix(test_dist_matrix[, test_comb_matrix[, i]]))))
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you Ronak!